# axios log and render log showing different things next js

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js

I'm somewhat new to React and Next JS and I am wondering what is happening to my data when it gets passed to my state. Here is the relevant code...

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
   this.state = {
        usersByName: this.props.usersByName,
   }   
} 

static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
const props = axios
  .post('http://localhost:3000/api/club', { clubId: query.clubid })
  .then((res) => {
      //Group array by users
      const usersByName = rbd.reduce((bet, value) => {
        if (!bet[value.name]) {
          bet[value.name] = []
        }
        bet[value.name].push(value)
        return bet
      }, {})

      res.data.payloadClub.map(function (u, x) {
          //Does some stuff here that isn't important
          usersByName[u.name].lastweekroi = -10
          usersByName[u.name].thisweekroi = -10
      })
      console.log(usersByName['tester'].lastweekroi) 
      return {
        usersByName: usersByName,
      }
return props
}


render() {
   console.log(this.state.usersByName['tester'].lastweekroi) 
   return (
       //Do stuff
   )
}
```

One console log in the inspector does not show the same values as the terminal window does?
[image]
[image]

Can anyone explain why my two console logs differ when I am returning the same variable into my state?
Is seems to lose the data that I added when pass to the state.

EDIT: lastweekroi and thisweekroi do not exist in the initial reduce value "usersByName" I'm trying to add it as another new variable

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `this.props. usersByName`, which is how you'd access values returned from `getInitialProps`. Also a bigger issue is that you are trying to directly manipulate `usersByName` rather than using setState or similar.

Comment: You may want to fix your code first, you seem to be missing some closing brackets in `getInitialProps`.

Comment: Sorry I probably just missed it in the copying and editing our garbage. It's still happening though :(